Next redirect with Auth supabase
I'm trying to figure out how to redirect some routes when the user is (or is not) logged. The snippet from the docs is like this:
export const updateSession = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  // Create an unmodified response
  let response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: request.headers,
    },
  });

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value }) =>
            request.cookies.set(name, value),
          );
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request,
          });
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            response.cookies.set(name, value, options),
          );
        },
      },
    },
  );

  // This will refresh session if expired - required for Server Components
  // https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs
  const user = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (
    !["/sign-in", "/sign-up", "/forgot-password", "/auth/callback"].includes(
      request.nextUrl.pathname,
    ) &&
    !user.data.user
  ) {
    const newResponse = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/sign-in", request.url), request);
    response.cookies.getAll().forEach(({ name, value, ...options }) => {
      newResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options);
    })

    return newResponse;
  }

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === "/" && !!user.data.user) {
    const newResponse = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/influencers", request.url), request);
    response.cookies.getAll().forEach(({ name, value, ...options }) => {
      newResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options);
    })

    return newResponse;
  }

  return response;
};

But I'm not sure whether this is the correct way of doing it

I was trying this now:
    const newResponse = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/influencers", request.url), request);
    response.cookies.getAll().forEach(({ name, value, ...options }) => {
      newResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options);
    })

    return newResponse;
  }```
Not sure if that is correct
